# How to paginate custom queries with group by?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the following JPQL query being mapped to a custom projection. The query is working correctly until I set the size attribute at the pagination object.

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM e.time) AS week "
        + "COUNT(r.id) AS total FROM MyEntity e "
        + "LEFT JOIN e.relationship r GROUP BY week")
Page<WeeklyReport> findWeeklyReport(Pageable pageable);
```

Hibernate fails with the error `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'week' in 'group statement'` after running the following query:

```sql
select count(entity0_.id) as col_0_0_ from entity entity0_
left outer join relationship relationship1_ on entity0_.id=relationship1_.tide_id
group by week
```

How can I have the same query without my group name break the pagination above?

The error does not happen if the size is not defined.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting -- does "GROUP BY 1" works?

Comment: "GROUP BY 1" makes my query return only 1 element regardless of the filters.

Comment: did you ran it in mysql directly?

Comment: My mistake, I had another attribute there. It is still not working because it adds the groups to that query again. Now it fails with `Can't group on 'col_0_0_'`.